# Nifi Stop all Processors from Shell

Tags: apache-nifi

For administration purposes I'm looking for an option or command to pause/stopp all Nifi Processes on the shell. Is there a way to do that or did I misunderstood the concepts behind.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195119/how-to-create-connection-and-delete-of-a-processor-in-apache-nifi-using-curl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use curl to send an api request telling it to stop the main canvas PG

```
curl --tlsv1.2 -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT -d '{"id":"PG ID","state":"STOPPED"}'  http://nifi-server-ip:port/nifi-api/flow/process-groups/PG ID
```

This will stop all PG/Processors that are on the main canvas.

To get the PG Id to go to the main NiFi canvas and is the long id under the Operate dashboard.

Comment: NiFi has a shortcut for the root Process Group, you can use 'root' instead of the ID.

Answer (score 7):

If you are comfortable using Python, then my project NiPyApi supports this:

```
from nipyapi import config, canvas
_ = [canvas.schedule_processor(li, 'STOPPED') for li in canvas.list_all_processors()]
# Stops all processors anywhere in NiFi
```

You can clone it on Github: https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi
These particular calls are new and will be released to Pypi soon.

Comment: This call is now available in NiPyApi 0.7.0 on Pypi